# How can i turn off discrete VGA during boot?

Tags: linux, boot, opensuse

I have mux-less Intel/ATI hybrid graphics. I can't install fglrx driver, because of it's compatibility with Xorg. So i want to have pernamently disabled discrete VGA.

I type that command after every start-up:

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

But it's boring, so i want to have this command automatically executed at during boot.

Comment: If you are interested, I wrote a script that removes unused kernel modules.  Removing them not only prevents loading unwanted modules like broken drivers or unused ports like yenta-socket, but it speeds up booting too.  It may not exactly be on topic though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a file boot.local in /etc/init.d. This file is used to execute local commands during start up. You can add your command to power off the discrete card to this file.

Comment: +1.Thanks. I've also blacklisted radeon, because of long udev processing and modprobed it there.